# Pass an object from collection to sub - Keep updated result of obect in collection

Tags: excel, vba

I want to pass an object from a collection to a sub and make it so that the object stored in the collection is updated.

I have tried to pass the item ByRef or ByVal it does not change the outcome

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As New Collection
i = 2
c.Add i
Call testtest(c(1))
Debug.Print c(1) ''I want this to return 3
End Sub

Sub testtest(i As Integer)
i = i + 1
End Sub
```

Example is with an integer but my actual problem use an object.

Comment: "If you want to pass a variable by reference, you’ve got
to pass the variable, period" -- read the full article why this is like that at https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/15/what-are-the-vbscript-semantics-for-object-members/

Comment: So is there a solution besides rewriting the item in the collection with an updated copy after each modification ?

Comment: With an `Integer`, no. With an object, ...we'd need an actual relevant [mcve] showing us what's not working.

Comment: Object is custom class.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer` is a *value*. The way *values* are stored in a `Collection`, to replace it you need to remove and re-add the new value.

Objects are different: what the collection stores isn't the object itself, but a pointer ("reference") to it. And whether you pass that pointer `ByRef` (a reference to that pointer) or `ByVal` (a copy of that pointer), you're still passing a reference to the exact same object.

Assuming `Class1` has a `Foo` property...

```
Private Sub Test(ByVal obj As Class1)
    obj.Foo = obj.Foo + 1
End Sub
```

...then `Foo` gets incremented and the object in the collection is updated.

Like values, you can't just replace the object pointer that's stored in the collection - you need to remove and then re-add the new object if you want to do that.

Comment: Thank you, at least I have learned some uncomon behavior.
Good thing I tried with an integer first in the end.

Comment: @DrinkWater TBH I was wondering why you would ask about an integer when you meant to work with an object... it's apples vs bananas!

Comment: Yeah in the end, Storax code made me realise it should work with object so I tried which left me confused but you explained the why in a way I could understand.
I'm still a bit confused about what will be stored by pointer and not in collection now.

Comment: @DrinkWater what you're confused about is, I suspect, more about the very nature of objects, which is indeed confusing if you're not familiar with them. Objects are a run-time thing, independent of your code: an object variable isn't an object, it's a *reference* (pointer) to one. So what the collection is storing, isn't an object, but a *reference* to that object. You need to play with object variables to really grasp the concept, e.g. `Set a = b`, then `Set b = Nothing`, use breakpoints (F9), run code line by line (F8), inspect local variables and see how they're affected. You'll get there!

Comment: Woa so even = is different with object. I didn't knew that. 
Sub test()
Dim a As New Classe1
Dim b As New Classe1
b.p1 = 2
Set a = b
Debug.Print a.p1
b.p1 = 12
Debug.Print a.p1
a.p1 = 50
Debug.Print b.p1
Set b = Nothing
Debug.Print a.p1
End Sub

This returned very interesting results !

Comment: @DrinkWater `Dim ...As New` is a trap... it makes an auto-instantiated object that reacts very surprisingly to being set to `Nothing` - best to keep the declaration (`Dim`) separate from the assignment (`Set`).